# CordovaHttp and Angular Post - no response

Tags: angularjs, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm using CordovaHTTP with Angular and injected the Cordova HTTP into a service. I haven't found many examples on how to implement a POST so below is what I did so far. The issue I'm having is that the post block never reaches the success or error blocks and my debug statements are not getting printed.

Does this look correct?

Calling function:

```
this.authenticate = function ( code, data, callback ) {
    try {
        // Build url
        var url = o.buildServerUrl(o.loginUrl, code);

        RestService.post(url, data, function(response) {

            if (response.status === o.HTTP_STATUS_OK) {
                ...
            }
        callback(response);
    });
}
catch(err) {
    var response = o.createServerErrorResponse(o.MSG_SERVER_ERROR);
    callback(response);
}
```

}

Service:

```
oApp.service( 'RestService', function( cordovaHTTP ) {

    this.post = function ( url, data, callback ) {
        try {
            // Build url
            if (o.debug) console.log('Cordova REST: '+url);


            cordovaHTTP.post( url, data, {}, function(response) {
                if (o.debug) console.log('Rest ok');
                // Success
                var response = o.processServerResponse(response);

                callback(response);              

            }, function(response) {
                 if (o.debug) console.log('Response error');
                 var response = o.processCordovaServerResponse(response);
                 callback(response);            
            }); 

        }
        catch(err) {
            var response = o.createExceptionResponse(err.message);
            callback(response);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you show the code that calls the `post` function and passes the url, data and callback parameters?

Comment: I went ahead and added the calling function. Thanks!